# conditionally remove duplicates from database in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, select, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'd like to remove duplicates from the column 'value' but only if there was no change from the previous update. I read tutorials about lag and lead but couldn't find an example with removing duplicates.

Original:

```
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
| ID | subID | value |       updated_at       |
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:36:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:31:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:26:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.30  | 2020-02-16 07:21:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:16:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:11:25+01 |
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
| ID | subID | value |       updated_at       |
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:36:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.30  | 2020-02-16 07:21:25+01 |
|  1 |     2 | 2.20  | 2020-02-16 07:16:25+01 | 
+----+-------+-------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Your ID/subid don't look like what I'd expect an ID to look like! What's with all the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use lag or lead and remove by ctid:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE ctid IN
(
  SELECT
    ctid
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      ctid,
      value,
      LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id, subid ORDER BY updated_at) pre
    FROM 
      yourtable t
  ) t
  WHERE value = pre 
)
```

As with any delete query from the internet, run it against a copy of the table...

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. If you want the last row before earch value change, you can use `lead()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lead(value) over(partition by id, sub_id order by updated_at) next_value
    from mytable t
) t
where value <> next_value or next_value is null
```

On the other hand if you want first value after each value change, you can use `lag()` instead of `lead()` (the rest of the query should remain the same).